# mariadb refuses connection with laptop in home network

Tags: mysql, mariadb, pymysql

I have MariaDB running on a Raspberry pi. My desktop that is connected by cable can access and manipulate data but my Laptop gets a:

```
OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.0.18' (using password: YES)")
```

I modified my.cnf to involve:

```
skip-networking=0
skip-bind-address
```

and configured mysql.user to listen to 192.168.0.%:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host from mysql.user where host <> 'localhost'
    -> ;
+------+---------------+
| user | host          |
+------+---------------+
| root | 192.168.0.%   |
+------+---------------+
```

Why am I still getting denied? (I have no Firewall running on the Raspberry Pi)

Comment: did you put the lines at the end of my.cnf

Comment: Yes, they are at the end of the file.

Comment: then try with out bit and bind adress 0.0.0.0 also did you check the error log for clues?

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. As soon as I set bind 0.0.0.0 I cannot connect remotely at all anymore. 
To clarify, I can access and modify the database with mysql-workbench from my laptop. As soon as I use python with pymysql it throws that error. However, this exact configuration works without error from my desktop.

Comment: that is strange, pymysql, mysql connctor wprk with thesame parameters as workbench. So maybe try another mysql driver for a change

Comment: Vladislav is right, I simply mistyped the password. Had an extra space in the document that I didn't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly likely, connectionis denied because you mistyped the password.
"Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.0.18' (using password: YES)" , that message comes from the server.

Comment: Yupp, that's it, oversaw a trailing whitespace.  Thanks Vladislav!